# Invariant Violation findComponentRoot(...): Unable to find element on redux action dispatch

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

I have a component, which receives a certain prop from a route - let's call it `day`. Then, there is a part of redux state - `calendar`, which I get using `connect()` and `mapStateToProps`. Now, when a date is outside of the calendar, in `componentWillReceiveProps` I dispatch a redux action, to recalculate calendar again to include a date in it. The action is fully synchronous, no requests are being sent. In that case, I get the invariant violation from react:

```
findComponentRoot(..., .0.1.0.$20160122): Unable to find element
```

What in what I'm doing is causing the problem? I'm not doing any tables or nested paragraphs/forms. When I dispatch action with `setTimeout(..)`, everything works as expected, so I guess it's some concurrency issue.

This is how my component code looks like:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    if (!dateInArray(props.day, props.calendar)) {
        props.actions.calculateCalendar(props.day);
        // This works:
        // setTimeout(() => props.actions.calculateCalendar(props.day), 0);
    }
}

@autobind
dateToDiv(date) {
    const date8 = toDate8(date);

    return <Link className="daySelect" activeClassName="active" key={date8} to={`/date/${date8}`}>{toNiceDate(date)}</Link>
}

render () {
    return <div>{this.props.calendar.map(this.dateToDiv)}</div>
}
```

And this is more or less how my routes look like

```
<Route path='/' component={App}>
    <IndexRedirect to={`date/${today8()}`}/>

    <Route path='date'>
        <IndexRedirect to={`${today8()}`}/>

        <Route path=":day" component={DayView}/>
    </Route>
</Route>
```

Comment: Can you show us more code? For example, what does `this.dateToDiv` do?